# How to identify if Computer is Restarted or Switched ON after Shutdown

Tags: uefi, shutdown, reboot

Is there any way to find out if the PC was restarted or switched on after Shutdown?
Preferably in UEFI environment. Is there any settings/flag ?

Comment: The appropriate eventids would be logged.  Have you verified the event manager contains the information you are looking for?

Comment: My aim is to find it out before OS is loaded. Depending on the condition (restarted/shutdown), I need to perform a task in UEFI before loading any OS.

Comment: This information cannot be accessed from the UEFI.  UEFI isn't aware of which operating system is installed on a system.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know for UEFI firmware, but Windows generate event logs in System log with event ID 1074 after each shutdown/restart/power off. You can use Event viewer to see it.